# Atom Editor: Error when PHP is inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, atom-editor

I have the following code in a **PHP** page in ATOM:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <?php $testvar = "Test"; ?>

      <script> 
        var test = <?php echo $testvar; ?>;
      </script>

  </head>

  <body>

  <p> This is a test. </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

The page is doing exactly as planned on the PHP page but in Atom, everything after the `</script>` line is highlighting in red as in an error. What's going on here?

Here is a screenshot of the actual code I'm using. The above is an example but also has the same problem.

I have opened a [Issue claim](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13532) on the Atom support but I would like to try here as well to see if it's anything within the code.

Thanks!

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WaBW.png)
[image]

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks for the response. The IDE displays fine when I remove the   `<script type="text/javascript">
      // Storing JS Result
      var main_categories_array = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","',  $main_categories_array ).'"' ?>];
  </script>` but when it's added is the issue here.

Comment: Please don't significantly change your question after people post answers. Which code are you using? The code you added in your edit, or your "actual code" in the screenshot, which is causing syntax errors?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in your code, not in Atom. Your `echo` statement produces an unenclosed string:

```
<script> 
    var test = Test;
</script>
```

This results in a JavaScript error ("Uncaught ReferenceError: Test is not defined") because you are telling the interpreter to use a variable named `Test`, but none exists.

You need to produce a properly enclosed string, which you can do with [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
<script> 
    var test = <?php echo json_encode($testvar); ?>;
</script>
```

Based on your comment, you're actually trying to build an array, not just echo a string. You have this code:

```
var main_categories_array = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $main_categories_array ).'"' ?>];
```

If your array contains any quotation marks, like the simple "Test" example, you will get errors. So, your code should be:

```
var main_categories_array = <?php echo json_encode($main_categories_array); ?>;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I thought this could be it too (from reading online) and the page loads fine and does everything as planned. The problem here is the IDE  shows everything in red. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/IUyqK9z.png

Comment: @hinteractive02 Based on your comment, your code should be `var main_categories_array = <?php echo json_encode($main_categories_array); ?>;`

Comment: Ed, That is the code that I already have written - as it was in the screenshot I posted: http://i.imgur.com/IUyqK9z.png

Comment: @hinteractive02 and this is why you don't omit critical information from your post, but be sure to include a [mcve] of the actual problem. I answered your question as written, then you changed it. Frankly, that's very bad form. Also, the code you added is not the same as the code you said you're using in your comment on your question or that appears in your screenshot. One is correct, the other very wrong. So, which is it?

Comment: I tried to keep it as minimal as possible to show my problem with anyone using the **Editor** that can reproduce the issue...

Comment: @hinteractive02 keeping it minimal is useless if you aren't offering a complete and verifiable example of your actual problem. And you still haven't clarified which code you're using.

Comment: @hinteractive02 based one what you've posted, no, it's a bug in your code.

Comment: Seriously? No need to act like a clown here.. I provided code to easily copy + paste into a new atom PHP page to see if others are having the same issue as I did within the IDE when I ran a test. If not, review my actual code to see if there is any issues within the code itself.

Comment: @hinteractive02 I did review your code, but you ignored my comments. Please note that name-calling violates our ["Be Nice"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Answer (score 0):

That was an actual bug fixed in 1.13, released yesterday : 10th of January.

Sources :

- https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13532
- http://blog.atom.io/2017/01/10/atom-1-13.html

Answer (score -2):

**This is a bug with Atom.**

Posted here: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13532